# Table View How to get each cell to go to unique controller without having to keep on creating it again

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

So I have my Table View set up with all of its cells and stuff. How do I make each cell go to its own unique UIView Controller? I can't do this manually because my program allows the user to input as many cells as they want.

Comment: Please add way more detail to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one unique view controller to display information referenced by each list item in your default view controller. e.g. if you have a list of notes, you can have one view controller with the table cell view which holds the title of each note and a reference to the data details of each note, and one view controller for displaying the data in each note. You want swap out the data displayed in the view controller for each separate note. In other words, you should only need two view controller objects for such a situation.

A good tutorial for a table view application would be Simon Allardice's `iOS App Development and Swift Essential Training` at https://www.lynda.com.